# adding credit card option function in smart contract for minting NFT

Tags: solidity

I'm looking into adding a function to allow payments by cc during mint. Has anyone done this successfully and is willing to share how you went about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way for doing this is after user paying you need to   make the minting from your server and transfer it to the user or mint it directly to the user wallet